# Google Drive REST API - why doesn't "modifiedDate" query field return any results when listing children?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, children, google-api-java-client, modified-date

In my Java project I am using the Google Drive API in order to download files from a public Drive.

When I try to list the children of a certain folder according to some criteria everything runs as expected. Yet there is this **modifiedDate** field which does not return any results. No error arises, but the list is empty, despite writing a perfectly reasonable search clause (there should be quite a sum of files).
This is my code:

```
    Drive.Children.List firstRequest = service.children().list(folderId)
            .setQ("mimeType='application/pdf' and modifiedDate <= '2016-03-07T19:17:54.759Z'" );
    do {
        ChildList result = firstRequest.execute();
        for(ChildReference child: result.getItems()) {
            File file = service.files().get(child.getId()).execute();
            System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s): %s\n",
                    file.getTitle(), file.getId(), file.getCreatedDate());
        }
        firstRequest.setPageToken(result.getNextPageToken());
    } while (firstRequest.getPageToken() != null &&
            firstRequest.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Using the **Try It!** feature on the Google Developers' page the same query returns results as expected. The HTTP Request there is the following:
[image]

And this is the response:
[image]

When I run my Java app this is the request URL:

```
GET  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B3Y7hLeztp6SUVBCbnpRN0ZQVVU/children?q=mimeType%3D'application/pdf'%20and%20modifiedDate%20%3C%3D%20'2016-03-07T19:17:54.759Z'
```

The HTTP response is the following:

```
kind: drive#childList
etag: "TEeH8_qJkyJwjzQ-F4FJRbfwWxI/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B3Y7hLeztp6SUVBCbnpRN0ZQVVU/children?q=mimeType%3D'application/pdf'+and+modifiedDate+%3C%3D+'2016-03-07T19:17:54.759Z'
items: [


]
```

The requests are identical. But the responses are not...
What could be the reason?

**EDIT**

I have to mention that I tried to use a service account. This will be a desktop application, so I didn't necessarily want users to acknowledge the use of the Google API and be compelled to create a Gmail address in case they didn't have one and authorize the requests. Moreover, the application only accesses resources on a drive shared publicly and needs no information about the client.  However, the service account key has caused my current problem, while using an OAuth Client ID key allows me to get the desired results. 
 Which is the recommended way to deal with this scenario? Or maybe I got everything wrong about the OAuth2 framework?

Comment: run the query using the Try It Now feature of the documentation page, and also from your app. Compare the generated http request for both.

Comment: I have already done that. The point is that the Try It Now feature returns all the correct results while my code doesn't. As for the Http Request, I don't really know how to get it in Java... I can see no method for obtaining it.

Comment: Did you look at the raw http post parameters from Try It Now and compare it to your code? Paste both into your question.

Comment: I edited the post. To me it looks like it is OK.

Comment: Can you also paste the raw http from your app to compare

Comment: I added the request URL from the app.

Comment: @pinoyyid I do apologize for being insistent, rude or dumb, but I am having a real issue with this obstacle. Could you please suggest a way to approach the problem? Thank you!

Comment: If you compare the two GETs, the URL escaping is different. Shouldn't matter, but it's worth eliminating. Also can you paste the http response to your code, just to confirm that there are no errors.

Comment: @pinoyyid the building of the request URL is not up to me. It is acquired through this Java Api Client Library command:  service.children().list(folderId).buildHttpRequestUrl().    I posted the http response.

Comment: Hmmm. So I agree the URLs look the same. So next is to check the Access Token. Do Try It Now and from devtools/Network, save the request as a curl command. Test it to make sure it works (it will until the token expires). Then replace the token with the one from your app and see if it still works. Might be a scope/permissions thing.

Comment: Thank you very much, @pinoyyid. Due to your recommendation, I tested the Try It Now feature with a Google email address that only had a Service Account key and I got the same empty result list. The problem was that my app was using a Service Account key, but needed an OAuth Client ID key. Strangely enough, all the others query fields could be accessed with the former key, but not the "date" ones. I replaced the key now. But what can I do if I preferred not asking the client to authorize the app through a Gmail address?

Comment: Can you update your question with more information about your use case. Eg. are you using a (a) the user's own account, (b) your account, or (c) a service account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114517/discussion-between-ionna-and-pinoyyid).